Definite Integral of $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\phi}{k-(a+bcos(\phi))^2+(a+bcos(\phi))}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k\in \mathbb{C}$
I tried solving this integral introducing the unit circle parametrization on the complex plane
$$
z = {\rm e}^{{\rm i}\phi}\quad\mbox{and substituting}\quad \cos\left(\phi\right) =
{{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\phi} +
{\rm e}^{-{\rm i}\phi} \over 2}
$$
This results in the integral
$$
\oint_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{2\pi i}\frac{1}{z\left[k-(a + b\left(z + 1/z\right)^2/2 + a + b\left(z + 1/z\right)/2\right]}
$$

I struggled to find all poles of this integral in order to use the Residue Theorem.
I also tried $\tt WolframAlpha$ to compute the integral as it is in the Title but I exceeded the standard computation time.

Thank you for helping me, Efe.

You are missing a $d\text{[integration variable]}$.

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

The antiderivative is simple using the tangent half-angle substitution, grouping terms and using partial fraction decomposition

Computing this integral with residues is more of a chore in algebra, but it is still quite doable. Upon substituting $z=e^{i\phi}$ and recasting to a contour integral, you end up with
$$-\frac i\alpha \oint\limits_{\lvert z\rvert=1} \frac{z}{1+\frac\beta\alpha z+\frac\gamma\alpha z^2+\frac\beta\alpha z^3+z^4} \, dz$$
where $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\left(\dfrac{b^2}4,\dfrac{(2a-1)b}2,a^2-a+\dfrac{b^2}2-k\right)$. The denominator is reducible:
$$1+\frac\beta\alpha z+\frac\gamma\alpha z^2+\frac\beta\alpha z^3 + z^4 = \left(1+\delta z+z^2\right) \left(1+\epsilon z+z^2\right) \\
\implies \begin{cases}\dfrac\beta\alpha = \delta+\epsilon \\ \dfrac \gamma\alpha = 2+\delta\epsilon\end{cases} \\
\implies \delta,\epsilon = \frac{\frac\beta\alpha \pm \sqrt{\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2}-\frac{4\gamma}\alpha+8}}2$$
The integrand has a simple partial fraction expansion,
$$\frac i{\alpha(\delta-\epsilon)} \oint\limits_{\lvert z\rvert=1} \left(\frac1{1+\delta z+z^2} - \frac1{1+\epsilon z+z^2}\right) \, dz$$
and its poles are easier to identify as
$$z_{1,2} = \frac{-\delta\pm\sqrt{\delta^2-4}}2, z_{3,4} = \frac{-\epsilon\pm\sqrt{\epsilon^2-4}}2$$
Now the residues are easy to compute, but there's still the matter of discerning which, if any, are found in the circle...

Your solution is what I was looking for. Thank you !

$$I(\phi)=\int\frac{d\phi}{k-(a+bcos(\phi))^2+(a+bcos(\phi))}+\text{constant}$$
First steps of "the lazy method" :
$x=a+bcos(\phi)\quad\implies\quad \phi=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right)\quad\implies\quad d\phi=-\frac{dx}{b\sin(\phi)}=-\frac{dx}{b\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right)^2}}$
$$I(x)=-\int\frac{dx}{(k-x^2+x)\sqrt{b^2-(x-a)^2}}+\text{constant}$$
From WolframAlpha :

One have to be not lazy for the next steps which are more difficult than it seems at first sight.

Unfortunately this solution is too complicated, but still thank you !

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{k+(a+b\cos x)^2+a+b\cos x}
$$
$$
=
2\int_0^{\pi} \frac{dx}{k+(a+b\cos x)^2+a+b\cos x}
$$
Substituting $x=\pi-u$ in the second quadrant to maintain a simple-branched tan-function
$$
= 
2\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{k+(a+b\cos x)^2+a+b\cos x}
+2\int_{\pi/2}^\pi \frac{dx}{k+(a+b\cos x)^2+a+b\cos x}
$$
$$
= 
2\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{k+(a+b\cos x)^2+a+b\cos x}
-2\int_{\pi/2}^0 \frac{dx}{k+(a-b\cos x)^2+a-b\cos x}
$$
$$
= 
2\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{k+(a+b\cos x)^2+a+b\cos x}
+2\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{k+(a-b\cos x)^2+a-b\cos x}
$$
With https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution
$$
t=\tan\frac{x}{2};
$$
$$
\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac12( 1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}) = \frac12(1+t^2).
$$
$$
= 
4\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{1+t^2}\frac{1}{k+(a+b\cos x)^2+a+b\cos x}
+4\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{1+t^2}\frac{1}{k+(a-b\cos x)^2+a-b\cos x}
$$
$$
= 
4\int_0^1 dt\frac{1+t^2}{ (k+a^2-2ab+b^2+a-b)t^4 +(2k+2a^2-2b^2+2a)t^2 +k+a^2+2ab+b^2+a+b}
+(b\leftrightarrow -b)
$$
These are sums of the format (Gradsteyn-Ryzhik 2.161.1)
$$
\int \frac{dx}{a+bx^2+cx^4}
= 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{c}{h}[\int \frac{dx}{cx^2+f}-\int \frac{dx}{cx^2+g}], & b^2-4ac >0\\
\frac{1}{4c q^3\sin\alpha}[\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\ln\frac{x^2+2qx\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}+q^2}{x^2-2qx\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}+q^2}
+2\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\arctan \frac{x^2-q^2}{2qx\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}}
],
& b^2-4ac <0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where
$$
h=\sqrt{b^2-4ac} ;
$$
$$
f=\frac{b-h}{2};
$$
$$
g=\frac{b+h}{2};
$$
$$
q=\sqrt[4]{a/c};
$$
$$
\cos\alpha=-\frac{b}{2\sqrt{ac}};
$$
and Gradsteyn-Ryzhik 2.161.3
$$
\int \frac{x^2dx}{a+bx^2+cx^4}
=
\frac{g}{h}\int \frac{dx}{cx^2+g}
-\frac{f}{h}
\int \frac{dx}{cx^2+f}, \quad h^2 >0
$$
The sign of $h^2$ depends on whether $4k-1$ is positive or negative.

I was looking for a different solution, but thank you !
